I have no idea about the Jenkins flow
I downloaded Nginx, Node.js(express.js, PM2 for CD), PostgreSQL and Jenkins in windows.
I want to do CI / CD React Web Application.
I already make webhook for connecting Jenkins. And it works.
The problem is that I don't know how write Jenkins Script and what I'm writing on Jekins Script file.
For example, If the client directory has a change, The jenkins would build it. If the server directory has a change, The jenkins would pm2 start server.js. What if the both of directories are changed? ... what should I do?
I tried this way, Pull git repository my Jenkins work place, copy it and build it. after that I send a real directory the client and the server.
My directory is divied into cleint and server like
root --- client
|
--- server
jenkins script file
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Checkout') {
            steps {
                checkout scm
            }
        }
        
        stage('Build Client') {
            steps {
                dir('client') {
                    powershell 'npm i'
                    powershell 'npm run build'
                }
                
                powershell 'Copy-Item -Path C:\\ProgramData\\Jenkins\\.jenkins\\workspace\\github-webhook\\client -Destination C:\\APH_template\\client -Recurse -Force'
            }
        }
        
        stage('Build and Deploy Server') {
            steps {
                dir('server') {
                    powershell 'npm i'
                }
                
                powershell 'Copy-Item -Path C:\\ProgramData\\Jenkins\\.jenkins\\workspace\\github-webhook\\server -Destination C:\\APH_template\\server -Recurse -Force'
                
                script {
                   
                    def pm2List = powershell(script: 'pm2 list | findstr server', returnStatus: true)
                    if (pm2List == 0) {
                        powershell 'pm2 reload server.js'
                    } else {
                        powershell 'pm2 start server.js'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post {
        always {
            
            cleanWs()
        }
    }
}

I want to know Jenkins flow
